# Analyzing FACS Data

Tags: anova, t-test, chi-squared-test

I have three FACS cell sorting datasets and I'm trying to find the best statistical test. The problem is that the data is in percentages, and I've spent all month searching for a test with no luck.

```
Sample         GreenCells    RedCells   BlueCells  TotalCellsSorted
 1                  4500      4600          1200      19000
 2                  6400      11500         1800      34000
 3                  6400      6500          1700      25000
```

I want to prove statistically that the red cells vary significantly, and the blue and green cells remain relatively consistent. Total cells vary due to the fact they may be lost during the separation process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason, why there are no absolute cell counts instead of just percentages? As far as I remember, FACS is usually done with lots of cells, so those hopefully big numbers would really help. Try to get those numbers out of the computer who must have counted them.  Or can you give a safe lower limit for how many red cells there have been? Otherwise, you get down to just three observations and big rounding errors in the red cells.

Comment: Without knowing the total number of cases it's impossible to assess statistical reliability. As an extreme example, having 1 head out of 3 tosses says little about whether a coin is fair. Having 1000 heads out of 3000 tosses says a lot.

Comment: @Bernhard I added the read numbers now. Well they're rounded. I just don't want someone to steal my work. The total number of cells sorted vary because they may be lost during the separation process (lyse/explode).

Comment: @EdM Real numbers were added. Total number of cells sorted vary due to the fact that I may lose some during the separation process.

Comment: If you want to test the null that 4500/19000 = 6400/34000 = 6400/25000 (for green cells), then you can use a chi-squared test. The result will obviously be that it's super-significant. The differences are huge. This of course only holds if your 4500 number is known exactly (as opposed to e.g. 4500 plus minus 1000).

Comment: How many biologic replicates of this experiment were done? (I'm assuming that Samples 1, 2, and 3 represent some type of experimental manipulations whose effects on cell types are being compared.)

Comment: @EdM Each "Sample" is a mixture of 7 embryos and each embryo has an estimated 5,000 cells. The embryos are the "same" category. I repeated the experiment for a total of 3 times on 3 separate days, i.e. Samples 1, 2, 3. The numerical difference is huge, but the percentages are close, except for the red cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the absolute numbers given, we can see the experiment as a number of binomial decisions. Instead of percentages we examine the probabilities behind each observations in a binomial model. You now need do define in more detail, what

> that the green cells vary significantly, and the red and blue cells remain relatively consistent

exactly means. What would persuade people to believe that. credible values for each of the probabilies could be visualized like this:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar=c(3,2,1,1))
curve(dbeta(x, 4500, 19000-4500), main = "Green cells", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,180))
curve(dbeta(x, 6400, 34000-6400), add= TRUE)
curve(dbeta(x, 6400, 25000-6400), add= TRUE)

curve(dbeta(x, 4600, 19000-4600), main = "Red cells", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,250))
curve(dbeta(x, 11500, 34000-11500), add= TRUE)
curve(dbeta(x, 65400, 25000-6500), add= TRUE)

curve(dbeta(x, 1200, 19000-1200), main = "Blue cells", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,180))
curve(dbeta(x, 1800, 34000-1800), add= TRUE)
curve(dbeta(x, 1700, 25000-1700), add= TRUE)
```

[image]

I feel this is proof enough, for how you worded the problem. If you want a formal test, we need a more precise wording, what to test.

Comment: @Bernard I made a typo. I wanted to prove that the red cells vary significantly.

Comment: Please try to reword "vary significantly" more exact. If you mean, that the three Samples have different red cell shares (Samples 1 to 3 do not have the same relative red cell count), then a simple $\chi^2$-Test of independence will suffice. `chisq.test(matrix(c(4600,19000-4600,11500,34000-11500,6500,25000-6500), ncol=3))` Or displaying, that the three curves above don't overlap.

Comment: Yes I apologize. What you wrote is better way of phrasing the question. Statistics is not my strong suit.